# Manage visibility between projects and users on Jira

Tags: project-management, project, jira

I know that we have groups and roles but I cant figure out how to separate users from projects. So I want to make projectA visible for DeveloperA and projectB for DeveloperB.

Maybe some tutorial on how to do this? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [JIRA project level security documentation.](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Configuring+project+specific+security)

Or if you want to drill down to issue level, that information is [here.](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Configuring+Issue-level+Security)

Answer (score 0):

Use (or create) a project role, e.g. Developers
In Project A add Dev A to the role.
In Project B add Dev B to the same role.
In the permission scheme used by both projects grant the Browse Projects permission to the Developers role (not a group)
That's it!

Answer (score 0):

The key is to decide how you want to manage permissions; by roles typically allows more control whereas by group typically involves less overhead to manage (roles have to be specified per project). If you are unclear on how to set a permission scheme up look here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Managing+Project+Permissions.
Depending on how many users/groups/roles you are trying to manage, you can also assign permission to individual users.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately JIRA is really poorly setup to support project by project visibility. Is it possible? Without a doubt. Does it take a lot of unnecessary setup? Most definitely. These two comments found in JIRA's own documentation alludes to the amount of setup involved:

> "in order to accomplish a security configuration which fits your company exactly, it will require a good amount of time, effort, and imagination on your part"
>
> "there is no way to automatically assign users to certain groups without massive customizations to the JIRA environment"

Ok, now that you know there's going to be some work involved, your focus should be centered around creating groups and setting up permission schemes -- both of which you'll have to do for each project or logical grouping of users based on a specific client, division, department, internal, etc. Here is some specific JIRA documentation on getting that setup:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA051/Using+Project+Level+Security+with+User+Groups